# Simple v-model vue.js on href instead of selectbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I use a `href-link` instead of `<select>` to change language with vue.i18n?

```
<select v-model="$i18n.locale">
    <option value="en">EN</option>
    <option value="da">DA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="$i18n.locale = 'en'">Set to EN</a>
<a href="#" @click.prevent="$i18n.locale = 'da'">Set to DA</a>
```